# C - Returning array as function argument

Tags: c, arrays, function

I was trying to pass a character array 'p' to a function 'func' and getting it copied to another argument 'arg' inside the function. But, the array is not getting copied, though I'm able to modify the content of 'p' in the 'func' and able to verify the changes in the main function, the 'res' doesn't get copied with the values from 'p'. It prints blank. I'm not sure what mistake I'm making.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char *c, int size, char *res)
{
        int i;
        printf("Printing c in func...\n");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                printf("%c",c[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        c[2] = 'j';
        res = c;
}

int main(void)
{
        char c[5]={'h','e','l','l','o'};
        char *p,*arg;
        int i, size = 5;
        p=c;
        arg = (char*)malloc(size);
        func(p,size,arg);
        printf("Printing p in main...\n");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                printf("%c",p[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Printing arg in main...\n");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                printf("%c",arg[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Printing c in func...
hello
Printing p in main...
hejlo
Printing arg in main...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, arguments to a function are passed by value. The location `res` and `c` does not exists after function execution reaches its end. Note that the changes you are doing is with the pointers itself and not the location pointer points to. So any changes to `res` will not be visible to `main`.

To make the changes visible to `main` you need to pass address of `arg` to function `func`.

`func` signature should be

```
void func(char *c, int size, char **res) ;
```

and its call from `main` should be

```
func(p, size, &arg);
```

Also change the assignment `res = c;` to `*res = c;` in function `func`.

In this case you are passing the address of pointer `arg` and changes are done to the location `res` is pointing to. `res` is pointing to the address of `reg` so any changes to the address pointed by `res` will be persist and visible to `main`.

Now see how it works. Initially when you call your function `func` after the suggested changes:

```
      +-----------+                (0x300 is a random memory location)
      |           |
arg   |   0x300   | <---------+
      |           |           |
      +-----------+           |
        0x100                 |
                              |
                              |
      +-----------+           |
      |           |           |
res   |   0x100   +-----------+
      |           |
      +-----------+
         0x200
```

When you assign `c` to `*res` (an alias of `reg`), `*res` will make `reg` to point to where `c` points to. Assuming string `hello` is stored at `0x500` then `*res = c` will make `reg` to point to `0x500`:

```
                                                            Array c (in main)
      +-----------+                                  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
      |           +--------------------------------->+ 'h' | 'e' | 'j' | 'l' | 'o' | '\0' |
arg   |   0x500   | <---------+                      +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------                                      
      |           |           |                       0x500  .... 
      +-----------+           |
        0x100                 |
                              | *res = c
                              |
      +-----------+           |
      |           |           |
res   |   0x100   +-----------+
      |           |
      +-----------+
         0x200
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, how are the changes to the array 'p' remains even after the function exits?

Comment: @Gomu; Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C pointers ar epassed by value to functions, so in your function:

```
void func(char *c, int size, char *res)
```

res is a totally different object than pointer passed to it

```
func(p, size, arg);
```

that is it is different than `arg`, but it points (only points) to the same location as `arg` pointed at the time it was passed to this function.

Therefore assignment

```
res = c;
```

mad inside that function changes only local pointer (the one inside the function). If you instead did

```
*res = *c;
```

then the *memory pointed to* would be changed and that would be visible from the outside of the function as the **memory pointed to** by original pointer is **same** as the one pointed by `res`. This is also why writing `'j'` to `c[2]` changes original array:

```
c[2] = 'j'; /* note: this is same as *(c + 2) = 'j'; and this is why it works - you
               are using memory pointed to by pointer */
```

If you need to change the pointer itself you need to pass address to that pointer instead:

```
void func(char *c, int size, char **res)
```

Comment: But, how are the changes to the array 'p' remains even after the function exits?

Comment: This is because c[2] = 'j' writes 'j' to the memory pointed to by c + 2.